# Qt layout is not working

Tags: c++, qt

I want to align button to right border of window in my app. I already tried to use layout but it's not working - button is still next to left border. 
Here code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{

this->setStyleSheet(
                    "QMenu {background-color: #555555; color: #EEEEEE; selection-background-color: #222222; border: 1px solid #222222;}"
                    "QMenuBar {background-color: #555555; color: #EEEEEE;}"
                    "QMenuBar::Item:selected {background-color: #333333; color:#EEEEEE;}"
                    "QMenuBar::Item:pressed {background-color: #111111;}"
                    "QToolBar {background: #555555; border-top: 1px solid #222222;}"
                    "MainWindow {background: black;}"
                    "QToolButton { background-color: transparent; border: none; }"
                    );

initButtons();
}

void MainWindow::initButtons()
{
QPushButton *playButton = new QPushButton(this); 
    playButton->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    playButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);");
    playButton->setToolTip("Play");
    this->layout()->addWidget(playButton);
    this->layout()->setAlignment(playButton, Qt::AlignRight);
}
```

Can someone tell me if I do it right or not? Why it's not working?

Comment: What layout did you set? "Returns the layout manager that is installed on this widget, or 0 if no layout manager is installed." (from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout)

Comment: I wasn't add any layouts. When try add new layout it says "  Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "", which already has a layout  ", so i trust that there is layout already.

Comment: Your example code should fully provide the context of the problem so people don't have to guess what you're doing (e.g., knowing you're working directly with a `QMainWindow` is integral).

Comment: It's been a while since I've used `Qt` but I believe you create a widget with your configured layout then you set it as the central widget of the main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add horizontal layout first

then add your widgets from left to right order

if you want to add space, you can use [spacer item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspaceritem.html#details).

```
QWidget * poCentralWidget = new QWidget(this);
QHBoxLayout * poHLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
poCentralWidget->setLayout(poHLayout);

// Spacer item
QWidget * poSpacerItem = new QWidget(this);

poSpacerItem->setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy::Minimum,QSizePolicy::Maximum);

// Add spacer item
poHLayout->addWidget(poSpacerItem);
// Add your button to the right side.
poHLayout->addWidget(playButton);

this->setCentralWidget(poCentralWidget);
```

Comment: I got this message:   "  QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "", which already has a layout  ". Button is still on left side.

Comment: I edited my answer after I realized you working with main window